# Deploying app with brokered component in physical device

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, winrt-component

I am developing an app using brokered components, using the Microsoft templates (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/527286e4-b06a-4234-adde-d313c9c3c23e) and following this step-by-step (http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2014/04/25/Building-Enterprise-apps-using-Brokered-Windows-Runtime-Components.aspx).

The reason of my problem is that I can execute/deploy the app without problems in local machine and in windows simulator, but when I deploy the app **in a device** it breaks with a `TargetInvocationException`

Description of the error:

> Requested Windows Runtime type 'MyNamespace.PrintService' is not registered

I get the error in my `ViewModelLocator`, in the line of code of the **getter of the ViewModel** which uses the brokered component:

```
    public SettingsViewModel Settings
    {
        get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SettingsViewModel>(); }
    }
```

The ViewModelLocator is an standard MVVM Light view model locator.

Here is the source code of my SettingsViewModel where I inject the brokered component:

```
    public class SettingsViewModel
    {
        public SettingsViewModel(IPrintService printService)
        {
            if (printService == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("printService");

            _printService = printService;

            InitializeCommands();
            InitializeActions();
        }

        ...
    }
```

Comment: Please review [How to create an MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and provide one *in the question itself.*  Then, identify the line of code that is causing the error.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. Is not the first time I ask something, and I think is not bad done my question...and I give all the information needed.

Comment: Show us your code that is breaking, and tell us which line is throwing the exception.

Comment: OK.  Now can you show us a little more context?  Maybe the entire class this property is in?

Comment: I think that is not very relevant :). The context is that I am using a brokered component which works fine on my laptop but not in physical device. I have post the guide I have followed and the exception and message exception I am getting

Comment: Robert, what do you need?

Comment: Please review [How to create an MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and provide one *in the question itself.*  Then, identify the line of code that is causing the error.

Comment: Ok, I have just edited my question.

Comment: Please reopen my question, is really important for me to solve this...

Comment: Question is reopened.  Now then, what is "XXXXX.PrintService"?

Comment: XXX is the namespace....I think it is not really important to show here the name of my customer.

Anyways...edited.

Comment: Hi, is PrintService your brokered component (Server) class?